# Generating spheres vertices, indices and normals?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am making a game in LWJGL and I am trying to make a procedurally generated planet (This question doesn't necessarily have to do with procedural terrain generation I know how to do it on a plane I assume it would be somewhat similar). My question is how do I programmatically generate a sphere with vertices, indices and normals and have the origin in the middle. I have looked around on the internet and could only find ways of generating the vertices. I am not asking for you to write the code but I would like a push in the right direction or some resources on doing so. The reason I want to generate my own sphere versus just importing one from a model is so I can easily edit the vertices height to make terrain, change the size of the sphere as well as easily change the poly count. My idea on how to do this is the following.

Get a vertex count of how many vertices should make up the circumference (Higher the number the higher the poly). Divide that number by 360 and then every triangle would be rotated by that number making a circle. And then gradually make the rest of the sphere using the same method. If this is the correct way of doing it how would I determine the indices and normals?

or

Get the vertex count and radius that the sphere should be from the origin. Determine the amount each triangle should be rotated. Start with two triangles on top at a the specified angle and world out from there until it reaches have way down the sphere at the same angle and then inverse the angle and have it finish the bottom in the same way. But again i'm not sure how to generate the indices, or normals.

Comment: You can create a sphere by stacking up layers, or you can tessellate an existing body (e.g., an icosahedron).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following pseudo code creates a sphere by stacking up `layerTile` layers and `circumferenceTile` vertex positions along the circumference of the layers.

The bottom an the top layer are caps and the layers in between are discs.
Since the center of the sphere is (0, 0, 0), the vertex points and the normal vectors have the same direction. The normal vectors are normalized and are directed from the center of the sphere to the spherical surface.

The texture coordinates are wrapped on both hemispheres. Therefore the endpoint of a half-disk of each layer is add as separated point. This is important to have points with the texture coordinate V = 1.0, otherwise it would be a dirty transition from the end of the texture to the beginning of the next part on the next hemisphere. On the polar caps, the vertex positions are multiple too, with different texture coordinates, in order to get clean texture transitions.

```
AddVertex( x, y, z, nvX, nvY, nvZ, u, v );
AddFace( i1, i2, i3 );
AddFace( i1, i2, i3, i4 ) {AddFace( i1, i2, i3 ); AddFace( i1, i3, i4 ); }

int circumferenceTile = 18;
int layerTile = 18;
float radius = 1.0;
```

Create the vertices and attributes:

```
int circCnt = (int)( circumferenceTile + 0.5f );
if ( circCnt < 4 ) circCnt = 4;
int circCnt_2 = circCnt / 2;
int layerCount = (int)( layerTile + 0.5f );
if ( layerCount < 2 ) layerCount = 2;

for ( int tbInx = 0; tbInx <= layerCount; tbInx ++ )
{
  float v = ( 1.0 - (float)tbInx / layerCount );
  float heightFac = Math.sin( ( 1.0 - 2.0 * tbInx / layerCount ) * Math.PI/2.0 );
  float cosUp = Math.sqrt( 1.0 - heightFac * heightFac );
  float z = heightFac;
  for ( int i = 0; i <= circCnt_2; i ++ )
  {
    float u = (float)i / (float)circCnt_2;
    float angle = Math.PI * u;
    float x = Math.cos( angle ) * cosUp;
    float y = Math.sin( angle ) * cosUp;
    AddVertex( x * radius, y * radius, z * radius, x, y, z, u, v );
  }
  for ( int i = 0; i <= circCnt_2; i ++ )
  {
    float u = (float)i / (float)circCnt_2;
    float angle = Math.PI * u + Math.PI;
    float x = Math.cos( angle ) * cosUp;
    float y = Math.sin( angle ) * cosUp;
    AddVertex( x * radius, y * radius, z * radius, x, y, z, u, v );
  }
}
```

Create the indices:

*Bottom cap*

```
int circSize_2 = circCnt_2 + 1;
int circSize = circSize_2 * 2;
for ( int i = 0; i < circCnt_2; i ++  )
  AddFace( circSize + i, circSize + i + 1, i );
for ( int i = circCnt_2+1; i < 2*circCnt_2+1; i ++ )
  AddFace( circSize + i, circSize + i + 1, i );
```

*Discs*

```
for ( int tbInx = 1; tbInx < layerCount - 1; tbInx ++ )
{
  int ringStart = tbInx * circSize;
  int nextRingStart = (tbInx+1) * circSize;
  for ( int i = 0; i < circCnt_2; i ++ )
    AddFace( ringStart + i, nextRingStart + i, nextRingStart + i + 1, ringStart + i + 1 );
  ringStart += circSize_2;
  nextRingStart += circSize_2;
  for ( int i = 0; i < circCnt_2; i ++ )
    AddFace( ringStart + i, nextRingStart + i, nextRingStart + i + 1, ringStart + i + 1 );
}
```

*Top cap*

```
int start = (layerCount-1) * circSize;
for ( int i = 0; i < circCnt_2; i ++ )
  AddFace( start + i + 1, start + i, start + i + circSize );
for ( int i = circCnt_2+1; i < 2*circCnt_2+1; i ++ )
  AddFace( start + i + 1, start + i, start + i + circSize );
```

See the following WebGL/JavaScript example:

```js
glArrayType = typeof Float32Array !="undefined" ? Float32Array : ( typeof WebGLFloatArray != "undefined" ? WebGLFloatArray : Array );

function IdentityMat44() {
  var m = new glArrayType(16);
  m[0]  = 1; m[1]  = 0; m[2]  = 0; m[3]  = 0;
  m[4]  = 0; m[5]  = 1; m[6]  = 0; m[7]  = 0;
  m[8]  = 0; m[9]  = 0; m[10] = 1; m[11] = 0;
  m[12] = 0; m[13] = 0; m[14] = 0; m[15] = 1;
  return m;
};

function RotateAxis(matA, angRad, axis) {
    var aMap = [ [1, 2], [2, 0], [0, 1] ];
    var a0 = aMap[axis][0], a1 = aMap[axis][1]; 
    var sinAng = Math.sin(angRad), cosAng = Math.cos(angRad);
    var matB = new glArrayType(16);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 16; ++ i ) matB[i] = matA[i];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++ i ) {
        matB[a0*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * cosAng + matA[a1*4+i] * sinAng;
        matB[a1*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * -sinAng + matA[a1*4+i] * cosAng;
    }
    return matB;
}

function Cross( a, b ) { return [ a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1], a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2], a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0], 0.0 ]; }
function Dot( a, b ) { return a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2]; }
function Normalize( v ) {
    var len = Math.sqrt( v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2] );
    return [ v[0] / len, v[1] / len, v[2] / len ];
}

var Camera = {};
Camera.create = function() {
    this.pos    = [0, 1.5, 0.0];
    this.target = [0, 0, 0];
    this.up     = [0, 0, 1];
    this.fov_y  = 90;
    this.vp     = [800, 600];
    this.near   = 0.5;
    this.far    = 100.0;
}
Camera.Perspective = function() {
    var fn = this.far + this.near;
    var f_n = this.far - this.near;
    var r = this.vp[0] / this.vp[1];
    var t = 1 / Math.tan( Math.PI * this.fov_y / 360 );
    var m = IdentityMat44();
    m[0]  = t/r; m[1]  = 0; m[2]  =  0;                              m[3]  = 0;
    m[4]  = 0;   m[5]  = t; m[6]  =  0;                              m[7]  = 0;
    m[8]  = 0;   m[9]  = 0; m[10] = -fn / f_n;                       m[11] = -1;
    m[12] = 0;   m[13] = 0; m[14] = -2 * this.far * this.near / f_n; m[15] =  0;
    return m;
}
Camera.LookAt = function() {
    var mz = Normalize( [ this.pos[0]-this.target[0], this.pos[1]-this.target[1], this.pos[2]-this.target[2] ] );
    var mx = Normalize( Cross( this.up, mz ) );
    var my = Normalize( Cross( mz, mx ) );
    var tx = Dot( mx, this.pos );
    var ty = Dot( my, this.pos );
    var tz = Dot( [-mz[0], -mz[1], -mz[2]], this.pos ); 
    var m = IdentityMat44();
    m[0]  = mx[0]; m[1]  = my[0]; m[2]  = mz[0]; m[3]  = 0;
    m[4]  = mx[1]; m[5]  = my[1]; m[6]  = mz[1]; m[7]  = 0;
    m[8]  = mx[2]; m[9]  = my[2]; m[10] = mz[2]; m[11] = 0;
    m[12] = tx;    m[13] = ty;    m[14] = tz;    m[15] = 1; 
    return m;
} 

// shader program object
var ShaderProgram = {};
ShaderProgram.Create = function( shaderList, uniformNames ) {
    var shaderObjs = [];
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderList.length; ++ i_sh ) {
        var shderObj = this.CompileShader( shaderList[i_sh].source, shaderList[i_sh].stage );
        if ( shderObj == 0 )
            return 0;
        shaderObjs.push( shderObj );
    }
    var progObj = this.LinkProgram( shaderObjs )
    if ( progObj != 0 ) {
        progObj.unifomLocation = {};
        for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < uniformNames.length; ++ i_n ) {
            var name = uniformNames[i_n];
            progObj.unifomLocation[name] = gl.getUniformLocation( progObj, name );
        }
    }
    return progObj;
}
ShaderProgram.Use = function( progObj ) { gl.useProgram( progObj ); } 
ShaderProgram.SetUniformInt = function( progObj, name, val ) { gl.uniform1i( progObj.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformFloat = function( progObj, name, val ) { gl.uniform1f( progObj.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniform2f = function( progObj, name, arr ) { gl.uniform2fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniform3f = function( progObj, name, arr ) { gl.uniform3fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformMat44 = function( progObj, name, mat ) { gl.uniformMatrix4fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], false, mat ); }
ShaderProgram.CompileShader = function( source, shaderStage ) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(source);
    if (shaderScript) {
      source = "";
      var node = shaderScript.firstChild;
      while (node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) source += node.textContent;
        node = node.nextSibling;
      }
    }
    var shaderObj = gl.createShader( shaderStage );
    gl.shaderSource( shaderObj, source );
    gl.compileShader( shaderObj );
    var status = gl.getShaderParameter( shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
    return status ? shaderObj : 0;
} 
ShaderProgram.LinkProgram = function( shaderObjs ) {
    var prog = gl.createProgram();
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderObjs.length; ++ i_sh )
        gl.attachShader( prog, shaderObjs[i_sh] );
    gl.linkProgram( prog );
    status = gl.getProgramParameter( prog, gl.LINK_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    gl.useProgram( null );
    return status ? prog : 0;
}
        
function drawScene(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById( "model-canvas" );
    Camera.create();
    Camera.vp = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
    var currentTime = Date.now();   
    var deltaMS = currentTime - startTime;
        
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    var texUnit = 0;
    gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 + texUnit );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureObj );
    
    // set up draw shader
    ShaderProgram.Use( progDraw );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformMat44( progDraw, "u_projectionMat44", Camera.Perspective() );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformMat44( progDraw, "u_viewMat44", Camera.LookAt() );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniform3f( progDraw, "u_lightDir", [-1.0, -0.5, -2.0] )
    ShaderProgram.SetUniform3f( progDraw, "u_color", [1.0, 0.5, 0.0] )
    var modelMat = IdentityMat44()
    modelMat = RotateAxis( modelMat, CalcAng( currentTime, 13.0 ), 0 );
    modelMat = RotateAxis( modelMat, CalcAng( currentTime, 17.0 ), 1 );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformMat44( progDraw, "u_modelMat44", modelMat );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformInt( progDraw, "u_texture", texUnit );
    
    // draw scene
    bufObj = bufSphere;
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.inPos );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.inNV );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.inTex );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.pos );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( progDraw.inPos, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.nv );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( progDraw.inNV, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.tex );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( progDraw.inTex, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inxLen, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.inPos );
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.inNV );
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.intex );
}

var startTime;
function Fract( val ) { 
    return val - Math.trunc( val );
}
function CalcAng( currentTime, varervall ) {
    return Fract( (currentTime - startTime) / (1000*varervall) ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
}

var sphere_pts = [];
var sphere_nv = [];
var sphere_tex = [];
var sphere_inx = [];
function AddVertex( x, y, z, nvX, nvY, nvZ, u, v )
{
     sphere_pts.push( x, y, z );
     sphere_nv.push( nvX, nvY, nvZ );
     sphere_tex.push( u, v ); 
}
function AddFace( i1, i2, i3, i4 )  {
    sphere_inx.push( i1, i2, i3 );
    if ( i4 )
        sphere_inx.push( i1, i3, i4 );
}

var gl;
var progDraw;
var bufSphere = {};
var textureObj;
function sceneStart() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById( "model-canvas");
    var vp = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
      return;

    progDraw = ShaderProgram.Create( 
      [ { source : "draw-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
        { source : "draw-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
      ],
      [ "u_projectionMat44", "u_viewMat44", "u_modelMat44", "u_lightDir", "u_texture" ] );
    progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw, "inPos" );
    progDraw.inNV = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw, "inNV" );
    progDraw.inTex = gl.getAttribLocation( progDraw, "inTex" );
    if ( progDraw == 0 )
        return;

    // create sphere vertices
    var layer_size = 16, circum_size = 32, radius = 1.0;
    var circCnt = circum_size;
    var circCnt_2 = circCnt / 2;
    var layerCount = layer_size;
    for ( var tbInx = 0; tbInx <= layerCount; tbInx ++ )
    {
        var v = ( 1.0 - tbInx / layerCount );
        var heightFac = Math.sin( ( 1.0 - 2.0 * tbInx / layerCount ) * Math.PI/2.0 );
        var cosUp = Math.sqrt( 1.0 - heightFac * heightFac );
        var z = heightFac;
        for ( var i = 0; i <= circCnt_2; i ++ )
        {
          var u = i / circCnt_2;
          var angle = Math.PI * u;
          var x = Math.cos( angle ) * cosUp;
          var y = Math.sin( angle ) * cosUp;
          AddVertex( x * radius, y * radius, z * radius, x, y, z, u, v );
        }
        for ( var i = 0; i <= circCnt_2; i ++ )
        {
          var u = i / circCnt_2;
          var angle = Math.PI * u + Math.PI;
          var x = Math.cos( angle ) * cosUp;
          var y = Math.sin( angle ) * cosUp;
          AddVertex( x * radius, y * radius, z * radius, x, y, z, u, v );
        }
    }
    
    // bottom cap
    var circSize_2 = circCnt_2 + 1;
    var circSize = circSize_2 * 2;
    for ( var i = 0; i < circCnt_2; i ++ )
        AddFace( circSize + i, circSize + i + 1, i );
    for ( var i = circCnt_2+1; i < 2*circCnt_2+1; i ++ )
        AddFace( circSize + i, circSize + i + 1, i );

    // discs
    for ( var tbInx = 1; tbInx < layerCount - 1; tbInx ++ )
    {
        var ringStart = tbInx * circSize;
        var nextRingStart = (tbInx+1) * circSize;
        for ( var i = 0; i < circCnt_2; i ++ )
            AddFace( ringStart + i, nextRingStart + i, nextRingStart + i + 1, ringStart + i + 1 );
        ringStart += circSize_2;
        nextRingStart += circSize_2;
        for ( var i = 0; i < circCnt_2; i ++ )
            AddFace( ringStart + i, nextRingStart + i, nextRingStart + i + 1, ringStart + i + 1 );
    }

    // top cap
    var start = (layerCount-1) * circSize;
    for ( var i = 0; i < circCnt_2; i ++ )
        AddFace( start + i + 1, start + i, start + i + circSize );
    for ( var i = circCnt_2+1; i < 2*circCnt_2+1; i ++ )
        AddFace( start + i + 1, start + i, start + i + circSize );
    
    bufSphere.pos = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufSphere.pos );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( sphere_pts ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    bufSphere.nv = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufSphere.nv );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( sphere_nv ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    bufSphere.tex = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufSphere.tex );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( sphere_tex ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    bufSphere.inx = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufSphere.inx );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( sphere_inx ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    bufSphere.inxLen = sphere_inx.length;

    var texCX = 128;
    var texCY = 128;
    var texPlan = [];
    for (ix = 0; ix < texCX; ++ix) {
        for (iy = 0; iy < texCY; ++iy) {
            var val_x = Math.sin( Math.PI * 12.0 * ix / texCX )
            var val_y = Math.sin( Math.PI * 12.0 * iy / texCY )
            var r = val_x < -0.33 ? 0 : ( val_x < 0.33 ? 127 : 255 );
            var g = val_x < -0.33 ? 255 : ( val_x < 0.33 ? 127 : 0 );
            var b = val_y < -0.33 ? 0 : ( val_y < 0.33 ? 127 : 255 );
            texPlan.push( r, g, b, 255 );
        }
    }
    textureObj = gl.createTexture();
    gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, textureObj );
    gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, texCX, texCY, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array( texPlan ) );
    gl.pixelStorei( gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT );

    startTime = Date.now();
    setInterval(drawScene, 50);
}
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;
attribute vec3 inPos;
attribute vec3 inNV;
attribute vec2 inTex;
varying float NdotL;
varying vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 u_projectionMat44;
uniform mat4 u_viewMat44;
uniform mat4 u_modelMat44;
uniform vec3 u_lightDir;

void main()
{
    vec3  modelNV = mat3( u_modelMat44 ) * normalize( inNV );
    vec3  normalV = mat3( u_viewMat44 ) * modelNV;
    vec3  lightV  = normalize( -u_lightDir );
    NdotL         = max( 0.0, dot( normalV, lightV ) );
    texCoord      = inTex;

    vec4 modelPos = u_modelMat44 * vec4( inPos, 1.0 );
    vec4 viewPos  = u_viewMat44 * modelPos;
    gl_Position   = u_projectionMat44 * viewPos;
}
</script>

<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
varying float     NdotL;
varying vec2      texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
    vec3 texColor = texture2D( u_texture, texCoord.st ).rgb;
    vec3 lightCol = (0.2 + 0.8 * NdotL) * texColor.rgb;
    gl_FragColor  = vec4( lightCol.rgb, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<body onload="sceneStart();">
    <canvas id="model-canvas" style="border: none;" width="256" height="256"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: And would the normals be calculated in the same way that Tobias Ribizel said?

Comment: Oh alright that makes sense. Thank you for your help and detailed answer it is helping alot.

Answer (score 2):

#### Generating the vertex positions and normals

The easiest way is to start from a [spherical coordinate system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) where you can imagine a regular grid spacing from -90° to 90° (or -pi to pi in radial angles) on the latitude and from 0 to 360° on the longitude. If you transform this grid from spherical coordinates to cartesian coordinates (with radius = 1 or some other radius you want)

The normals are actually very easy to generate: Since the center of the sphere lies at `(0,0,0)`, the normal of the vector `(x,y,z)` is just the normalized vector `(x,y,z)/length(x,y,z)`

#### Generating the indices

Remember how I described the sphere as a regular grid?
To be more precise, the points on your grid are `(longitude, latitude)` pairs of the form
`(i * lon_step_size - 90°, j * lat_step_size)`. You can simply index them by flattening the 2D array storing the vertices using the indexing `i * num_lat_steps + j`,
where `num_lat_steps - 1` is the maximal value for `j`.
To build the index buffer, you just need to use this indexing to connect the vertices at `(i,j),(i+1,j),(i,j+1)` and at `(i+1,j+1),(i,j+1),(i+1,j)` to a triangle for every index pair `(i,j)` inside the grid.

Note that with this approach, there are two points (at lat=90° or lat=-90°) that appear multiple times in the vertex buffer. If you want to eliminate these duplicates, your indexing becomes a bit more tricky, but you probably won't have to, anyways (It's not that much of an overhead).